# VBA \ VB6 - Convert number to DATE

Tags: vba, vb6

VBA \ VB6 - 
I have a long number: `20141202153026`

which should be converted to a date\time (just to be turned back to a properly formatted date string) as:

```
2014/12/02 15:30:26
```

Using `CDate()` just isn't cutting it.

```
Format$("20141202153026", "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss")
```

Also seem to fail.
Need a direction here.

EDIT: i used jac's solution and it worked great.
One thing to remember though is to cast the result back to date with cDate() - to make sure locale settings kick in and arrange the year and the month at their right positions DD/MM/YYYY

```
 CDate(Format$("20141202153026", "####/##/## ##:##:##"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to go with Bond's answer for being more robust, but if you're looking for the fastest least code way out and just because I love alternatives you could format your date time string into a date format then convert that.

```
'number mask depends on the input being correct
CDate(Format$("20141202153026", "####-##-## ##:##:##"))
```

Comment: Love this.  Very creative use of `Format`.

Answer (score 8):

No easy way to do this other than just to just parse the string:

```
Const strText As String = "20141202153026"

Dim y As String, m As String, d As String
Dim h As String, n As String, s As String

y = Left$(strText, 4)
m = Mid$(strText, 5, 2)
d = Mid$(strText, 7, 2)
h = Mid$(strText, 9, 2)
n = Mid$(strText, 11, 2)
s = Right$(strText, 2)

Dim dtm As Date
dtm = DateSerial(y, m, d) + TimeSerial(h, n, s)

Debug.Print Format$(dtm, "dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss")       ' => "02/12/14 15:30:26"
```

**Edit:**

Though if your wanted to add a reference to the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` library, you could make it a little easier:

```
Dim re As New RegExp, dtm As Date
re.Pattern = "^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$"
dtm = re.Replace(strText, "$2/$3/$1 $4:$5:$6")

Debug.Print Format$(dtm, "dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss")       ' => "02/12/14 15:30:26"
```